# Scrapy Xpath Selector returning partial text

Tags: python, scrapy, html-parsing, parsel

I have some text in the `p` tag which may contain the additional tags like `em` within that.
When I pass the following text to `parsel` `XPath` selector and ask for the first `p` tag it returns me the partial string.

```
  from parsel import Selector

  selector = Selector(text="<div><p>Hel<em>l</em>o</p><p>World!</p></div>")

  for p in selector.xpath('(//div//p//extract())[1]'):
    print(p.get())
```

The output returned by the code is

`Hel` and the expected output is `hello`, what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```py
from parsel import Selector

selector = Selector(text="<div><p>Hel<em>l</em>o</p><p>World!</p></div>")

for p in selector.xpath('//div/p[1]/descendant-or-self::*/text()'):
  print(p.get())

# OR
print("".join([x.get() for x in selector.xpath('//div/p[1]/descendant-or-self::*/text()')]))
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you may will want to avoid the double slashes in your xpath. See [Working with relative XPaths](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#working-with-relative-xpaths)